# Unable to locate key in config db using wildchar?

Tags: uvm

I am not clear on why my lookup in config_db is returning null? My understanding is that config_db allows metacharacter "*" to match zero or more characters for the key. So not sure why it is failing.

Below is the trace from  +UVM_CONFIG_DB_TRACE. After the set, the first 2 get works even though they are called from different levels of hierarchy which matches my understanding that uvm_config_db is only doing string match. However, the next 2 get with '*' fails. Why is that?

```
[CFGDB/SET] Configuration 'uvm_a1.uvm_b1.key1' (type int) set by  =(int) 1

[CFGDB/GET] Configuration 'uvm_a1.uvm_b1.key1' (type int) read by uvm_a1.uvm_b1 = (int) 1

[CFGDB/GET] Configuration 'uvm_a1.uvm_b1.key1' (type int) read by uvm_a1 = (int) 1

[CFGDB/GET] Configuration '*.key1' (type int) read by  = null (failed lookup)

[CFGDB/GET] Configuration 'uvm_a1.*.key1' (type int) read by uvm_a1 = null (failed lookup)
```

Comment: Please could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score -1):

I think the wildcard only works with uvm_config_db::set but not with the get method